# Breaking from nested while loop

Tags: python-2.7

I have two nested while loops in my script like in the code below,

```
while next_page is not None:
    while 1:
        try:
            #Do Something
            break
        except:
            pass
```

Now when I use the break statement, it breaks both the while loop.
I just want to break from `while 1` and keep `while next_page is not None:` running until the next_page value is not None.

Is this possible? If yes, could someone please advise how to do that.

Thank you.

Comment: Documentation says `break` breaks innermost loop. I observe this behaviour for both python2 and python3. Do you have minimal example of your problem?

Comment: @keltar Thanks for replying. That is my thinking as well. But here it is breaking both the loops. Guess, the issue is something else then. And even rchang 's answer does help well, Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That `break` statement only exits that inner loop.  A concrete example:

```
while True:
  print "In outer loop"
  i = 0
  while True:
    print "In inner loop"
    if i >= 5: break
    i += 1
  print "Got out of inner loop, still inside outer loop"
  break
```

That outputs the following:

```
In outer loop
In inner loop
In inner loop
In inner loop
In inner loop
In inner loop
In inner loop
Got out of inner loop, still inside outer loop
```

This leads me to believe there is something else causing your execution to leave the outer loop - either `next_page` got assigned to something, or perhaps there is another `break` floating around.

Comment: Thanks, will accept your answer after the 5 minutes limit